# C program reads the end of file

Tags: c, eof

PLEASE LOOK AT THE EDIT AT THE END OF THIS TEXT
I have a test.dat which has 2 lines.
In the first line is a float number (5.0)
In the second line are two integer numbers, separated with by a " * ", such as 4*3
The float number is shown correctly (output:5.0000) but the second line is not shown. My teacher told me I made a mistake after the while loop. Fscanf reads the END of file, not the beginning.That's why I get random numbers as an output such as "65746* -8634364" I do not know, how to solve it.Your help would nice. Here is my C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float z1;
    int z2,z3;
    char line[255];

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("test.dat", "r");
    if (file==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(file, "%f", &z1);
    printf("%f\n", z1);

    while (fscanf(file, "%s", line)  == 1)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%d*%d", &z2, &z3);
        printf("%d * %d\n", z2,z3);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: I got a new warning after I followed the instructions of the first answer**
Warning Code: `In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[255]’ [-Wformat=]
  while (fscanf(file, "%s", &line) ==1)
  ^`

EDIT 2: The warning is gone, thanks to the first answer!! Still a problem: The second line's content is "4*3" , my output is "0*0" Why?

Comment: Please add the content of the _test.dat_ file to your question.

Comment: The test. dat is only a text file, that looks like this:
1st line: 5.0
2nd line: 4*3
That's it.

Comment: (Please do not change your question too much, as it may invalidate existing answers. There is also no need to add "Solved" anywhere in your question. The presence of an accepted answer is enough indication of that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s", &line) != EOF)
                       ^ wrong argument is passed to %s
```

You read a string into `line` , but `line` is declared as `char` variable -

```
char line;                 // will invoke UB if no space is left for '\0'
```

So, you need to declare `line` as `char` array. Some thing like this -

```
char line[255];            //make sure to leave a space for null character
```

**Note**-Probably don't test `fscanf` against `EOF` , write your loop condition as follows -

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s", line)==1)     //will return 1 only if it is successful
            /*           ^ note- don't pass here &line, just pass line  */
```

Comment: I can accept your answer in 4 minutes, so don't wonder, please :D Gonna make it as soon as possible.

Comment: Still, I got a new problem after your fix. It throws a warning:                                In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[255]’ [-Wformat=]
  while (fscanf(file, "%s", &line) ==1)
  ^

Comment: @Blnpwr  Answer to that lies in `while` loop I wrote in **NOTE** . **Don't pass `&line`** , just pass `line` in `fscanf`. You pass address of char array which is not which `%s` expects .

Comment: Is that line being used to consume the end-of-line characters?

Comment: The warning is still there.. Look at the edited question please.

Comment: I did, I passed "line". The warning is gone, but it does not show the content of the second line. My second line of the file is "4*3" , but the output is " 0 * 0" Can you explain why?

Comment: @Blnpwr That maybe because you already read it using `fscanf` in file and nothing is left to read for `fscanf` inside loop . Probably you don't need that `fscanf` in while loop condition .

Comment: Im going to try it without the fscanf and tell you then.

Comment: @Blnpwr Try to write your loop as follows - `while (fscanf(file, "%d*%d", &z2, &z3)==2)` and print values inside .

Answer (score 1):

You fill a char variable with fscanf. You should use a char* since you use %s in your format string.

Comment: It throws this error after the fix of the first answer:                                                   In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[255]’ [-Wformat=]
  while (fscanf(file "%s", &line) ==1)
  ^